# Why does list(None) in python give different exceptions in different terminals?

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, nonetype

I am writing a game in Python 2.7 and while debugging I found an exception I could not reproduce in the Python console. 
At some point in the script I used the list() function and used it on the return of another function like so:

```
var1 = list(otherfunction(arg1, arg2, andsoon))
```

When the other function returned None I got the exception:

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

But when checking it out in a new terminal at the Python console I got:

```
>>> newlist = list(None)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

Then I started a console in the terminal window that I ran the script in and tried again:

```
>>> newlist = list(None)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

Is there a good reason why the interpreter gives me different exceptions? Or are these exceptions (not callable and not iterable) simply interchangeable and is the difference of no concern?

For my script this does not matter, I would just like to understand what can cause different exceptions for (seemingly) the same operation in different terminal windows.

Some extra system info that could be relevant:

```
Python 2.7.10 (default, Jul  5 2015, 14:15:43) 
[GCC 5.1.1 20150618 (Red Hat 5.1.1-4)] on linux2
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce your issue. Of course, there exceptions are not interchangeable and means different things.

Comment: The two examples I posted from the console output are directly copy pasted. The one above that is made up to show how it started, but is irrelevant to the question.

Comment: I bet you have typed `list = None` somewhere (or, if not explicitly `None`, and expression that evaluates to None)

Comment: I agree with Andrea here, it's so easy to re-assign builtins, primitives etc in python. Assiging type = ... .is one of my faves too....

Comment: Yes! I do and that one gives me 'object is not callable'. I understand now! Tnx.